# can I get the launcher to "re see" open processes?

Tags: unity, bash, launcher, google-chrome

I've got about 8 gnome-terminal tabs open in one window. For some reason, the launcher is not aware of this window suddenly. When I click on the gnome-terminal symbol in launcher, it won't slide the existing windows into view (or bring them to front) it will just open a new gnome-terminal. Yesterday it was working fine, clicking the "lit up" gnome-terminal symbol in the launcher would slide me to the correct workspace (if needed) and bring gnome-terminal to front.

Same thing is happening with Google Chrome 32. It doesn't seem to be aware of open windows.

Is this a bug or some setting that I'm not aware of (that I managed to change anyway)?

`GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

```
Ubuntu:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

The natural solution is to just kill the gnome-terminal but I'd prefer not to, there's things running in there that I'd rather not kill.

Comment: Have you done something before the problem presents, like suspending the machine? Also, it's not bash but `gnome-terminal`, bash runs inside the terminal. (BTW, you can try scrolling over the icon and see if that works.)

Comment: thanks, fixed; I think I may have accidentally hit "show desktop" before this happened; I installed Docky and Docky sees the gnome-terminal but Unity does not.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like `bamfdaemon` has died or has problems. Check with `pgrep -l bamf`, is it running?

- If it is not running start is with `nohup /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon`
- If it is running then kill it with `killall bamfdaemon`, then click on one of your apps on the launcher which should restart the daemon (your first click though will still be handled wrongly, since it takes some time for the daemon to come up.) If it won't restart, then start it yourself like above.

Comment: It was running. Restarting it and clicking on an existing app doesn't seem to have helped. In the meantime I installed Docky and Docky _is_ seeing the gnome-terminal windows that Unity isn't. If that helps.

Comment: Do you have any open window which is behaving correctly or none of the windows are recognized by the launcher? (You said chrome and gnome-terminal working incorrectly, anything which is working correctly?)

Comment: It's an open window which is not "popping" back in place when I click on it: one gnome-terminal window with 7 tabs in it which doesn't show in Launcher. Clicking gnome-terminal opens a new terminal instead of popping the existing terminal into view.

Comment: @jcollum So you can switch to other open applications/windows from the launcher, the only you can't switch to is this particular gnome-terminal window?